# onepage checkout page is not loading

Tags: magento

I had updated a custom theme in magento 1.9 all goes well but when I click on "proceed to checkout" button on cart page (i.e http://mysite/checkout/cart/) it shows link(http://mysite/checkout/onepage/) but always redirects to home page

and If I change the theme to (rwd theme) then this page "link(http://mysite/checkout/onepage/)" runs well

what I am missing in my custom theme that unables the onepage checkout page to load correctly? PLEASE HELP

I checked admin settings  >System>Configuration>General>Web
secure base url and other settings all are ok but still I am not able to load to checkout. It still redirects to homepage.

I refer to this link http://www.neiltolbert.com/magento-ssl-checkout-redirect-fix/ for admin settings

Comment: enable developper mode, check log and add informations in your questions

Comment: there is nothing in logs.

Comment: strange.... show us your theme files which is involved in the checkout/onepage process

Comment: thanks but its because of col2 template missing in my theme. I had resloved this but now checkout steps are  not working.                              It shows as:  <div id="checkout-step-login" class="step a-item" style="display:none;">

Comment: contact your theme support

Comment: I recommend to you to add all useful informations in your original question for other users in your case

Comment: Your `System>Configuration>General>Web secure base url` is `https://your.site.com` and `System>Configuration>General>Web unsecure base url` is `http://your.site.com` ?

Answer (score 0):

If checkout page url is not correct then correct the url for redirection.

Check .htaccess file taht is rewrite mod is ON.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>   
// rewrite code here
</IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
```

And check url rewrite code of checkout page if custom rewrite code is available.

And Need to check your add to cart button action , Action url must be redirected to checkout page.